# im a beginner in python and i want to make an absent number teammate randomizer program with tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter, random

```
import random

from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.geometry("700x600")
win.title("pengocok keberuntungan")

isi = Entry(win,width=25,font =("arial",25))
isi.pack()

isi2 = Text(win,width=56,height=25,font=("arial",10))
isi2.pack()

mylist = (list(range(1,35)))
b =  random.sample(mylist,34)
print (b)

def acak():
    for i in b:
        pass

        isi.delete(0,END)
        isi.insert(END,i)
        isi2.insert(END,isi.get()+"\n")


acak_tombol = Button (win,text = "di acak",command =acak)
acak_tombol.pack(pady=20)

win.mainloop()
```

My problem is when I click the button it already randomize all my 34 friends instantly. What I want is that every time I click the "acak" button, 1 of my randomized classmates gets inserted into the textbox and can't be doubled until all my 34 friends get their teammate. By the way, how do I link that absent number with my 34 classmates? So what will pop up when the "acak" button is pressed is my friend's name and absent number is inserted into the text box one by one, not instantly like my problem.

Comment: Just... don't do the loop, then? I don't understand why this is confusing. You want a callback function that adds a single element of `b` to the two widgets. The inside of your loop does that.

Comment: i am sorry...i dont know how to call all items in a list one by one...so i use the loop because loop function can call all item in the list....

Comment: You don't need to do anything special except keep clicking the button. There should not be a loop in the code. You should write code so that the button handles one item. When you click the button again, it will handle another item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a random list first, and refer it one by one with an index, as you click the button. this way same number wont be repeated.

Please refer below code.

```py
import random

from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.geometry("700x600")
win.title("pengocok keberuntungan")

isi = Entry(win,width=25,font =("arial",25))
isi.pack()

isi2 = Text(win,width=56,height=25,font=("arial",10))
isi2.pack()

mylist = (list(range(1,35)))
b =  random.sample(mylist,34)
i=0
print (b)

def acak():
    global b
    global i
    if i<len(b):
        isi.delete(0,END)
        isi.insert(END,b[i])
        i+=1
        isi2.insert(END,isi.get()+"\n")


acak_tombol = Button (win,text = "di acak",command =acak)
acak_tombol.pack(pady=20)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you....this code is working...btw... what is the global function for??

Comment: `global`  is used to access variables that are declared outside the function in global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Move the line `b = random.sample(mylist, 34)` into the function. It will be executed every time you call the function.